# How to poll a file in Linux kernel space?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I opened a device file in Linux kernel space using `struct file *filp->f_op->open`.

Now I want to poll the opened device file before doing a read using `struct file *filp->f_op->read` or I want to read the device file once the data has arrived.

When I went through the Internet, I found a kernel function to poll called `poll_wait()`.
Can any one provide example how to use `poll_wait()` to function ?

Below is my pseudo code in kernel implementation :

```
struct file *filp;
filp->f_op->sys_open("/dev/ttySX") ---> Non blocking mode 
filp->f_op->read() --> Before reading i need to poll the opened device file .
```

Is the polling only way to find the data has arrived?

Comment: Not sure of what you really want to achieve, anyway if the file you opened is a char device, you will know when someone write to it in the write callback of the device structure I suggest you reading Chap. 3 of [Linux Device Drivers] http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/